# Opengl stripped surface when viewed under angle

Tags: opengl

I have a problem with stripped surface in my program.

I render some surfaces using OpenGL(Tao). I use triangle_strip.
To have a good 3D impression i use lighting. Normals are set correctly i thing.

At first I used crossProduct, now i use derivation of implicit function. Both methods seem to give right results, derivation is may be better because of precision. I see on the surface  vertical stripes. Two neighbor triangles in strip have different hue/shade. 1,3,5,7 ... and 2,4,6...  have the same hue/shade. The smaller viewing angle is the bigger the difference is. At 90° it's OK.

How can I get rid of the stripes?

Here you can see Images:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Initialization:

```
private float[] materialAmbient = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
private float[] materialDifuse = { 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f };
private float[] materialOdlesky = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
private float[] materialShininess = { 50.0f };
private float[] light_position = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
private float[] light_color = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f }

Gl.glShadeModel(Gl.GL_SMOOTH);
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
Gl.glHint(Gl.GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, Gl.GL_NICEST);
Gl.glDepthFunc(Gl.GL_LESS);
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, Gl.GL_AMBIENT, materialAmbient);
Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, Gl.GL_DIFFUSE, materialDifuse);  
Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, Gl.GL_SPECULAR, materialOdlesky); 
Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, Gl.GL_SHININESS, materialShininess);
Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_POSITION, light_position);
Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_DIFFUSE, light_color); 
Gl.glLightModeli(Gl.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, Gl.GL_TRUE);  
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING);
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);
```

Drawing Code:

```
double foo = 15;
        for (double v = -foo; v < foo; v += vStep)
        {
            if (v > foo - vStep)
                v = foo - vStep;
            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
            Gl.glColor3dv(_color);
            for (double u = -foo; u < foo + uStep; u += uStep)
            {
                if (u > foo)
                    u = foo;
                SetVextexAndHisNormal(u, v);
                SetVextexAndHisNormal(u, v + vStep);
                if (u == foo)
                    break;
            }
            Gl.glEnd();
            if (v == foo - vStep)
                break;
        }


 public void SetVextexAndHisNormal(double u, double v)
    {
        Vector v1 = ComputeCoordinatesAt(u, v);
        double x = (-2 / (_a + _a)) * v1.GetX();
        double y = (2 / (_b + _b)) * v1.GetY();
        double z = -2*_k;
        Vector normal = new Vector(x, y, z);
        normal.NornVector();

        Gl.glNormal3d(_normalSign * normal.GetX(), _normalSign * normal.GetY(), _normalSign * normal.GetZ());
        Gl.glVertex3d(v1.GetX(), v1.GetY(), v1.GetZ());
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Question is how to get rid of the stripes. Or whats the reason of the stripes.

Comment: Guessing here, but I think your normals aren't being computed or normalized correctly.  One thing you could do to verify that is render a line at each vertex to visualize the normals.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what your material and lighting properties are (i.e., what you set with `glMaterial`, `glLight`, etc.)

Comment: private float[] materialAmbient = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }
        private float[] materialDifuse = { 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f };
        private float[] materialOdlesky = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f }
        private float[] materialShininess = { 50.0f }

        private float[] light_position = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
        private float[] light_color = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f }

Comment: Seeing wiremesh could help too.

Comment: Code Added. I did it with normals and they looked nice.

Comment: I think its caused by fact that the triangles are slimmer a higher while |0 - u| rises(but still triangles easy to see).